# How to access the main dialogContext from a top level dialog?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, botframework

I am developing a bot using botbuilder v4 sdk for Node.js,

In the main middleware, we have the **onTurn()** function in which we create the dialog context (**dc**).

My question is how to access and modify the dialog context from a specific top level dialog?

```
async onTurn(context) {
  ...
  const dc = await this.dialogs.createContext(context);
  ...
}
```

I was thinking about creating a property in the conversationState and load the dc into it, then, get its value from the dialog.

Is this a recommended way?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what it is your are trying to accomplish? It's a little confusing.

Comment: Hi @StevenKanberg,

I am developing a multilingual bot, I referred the multilingual bot in the bot builder samples.

So I created a Locale property in the userState, this property will be updated once the locale is switched. To detect the locale, I am using Text Analytics API to detect the Locale.


What I am trying to do is the add the ability to switch locale in the middle of a dialog and then continue the same dialog without returning from the beginning.

Comment: To do that, I added a dialog called ChangeLanguage, in the onTurn() function, i checked first the initial locale, set it to the localeProperty and save changes in the user state.

I checked an other time if the locale is changed from the saved one.
If yes I started the changeLanguage dialog which will prompts the user to choose a new locale. Then, I updated the Locale property with the new locale, Finally, the conversation will return to the calling dialog.

Comment: The problem that I faced is that the locale wasn't changed immediately when we get back to the first dialog.

For example:
Given a Waterfall dialog "A" that contains a number prompt, text prompt and a date prompt. The text prompt will ask the user for his name and the date prompt will ask him for his birthday.

The dialog is started in English, when the bot asked for Name the user answer in french, so the ChangeLanguage dialog is activated and when it ends the bot should ask the user for its birthday in french. but it is not the case.

Comment: I found that the ancient text value of the prompt is stored in the main dialog context so when the locale is switched to french, the next prompt was shown in English. To solve this, I was thinking about sending the Dialog context to the Change Language dialog and update its values with the new locale text… but this doesnt' work.

I hope you'd understand the idea.